# Parse nltk chunk string to form Tree

Tags: python, parsing, tree, nlp, nltk

I have a file containing Strings like

```
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', 
[('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])
```

Is there a python function that parse the string to produce Tree structure again? I tried the [Tree.fromstring](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html#Tree.fromstring) function but it doesn't parse.

I generate these strings like below

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> pattern = """NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
... VBD: {<VBD>}
... IN: {<IN>}"""
>>> NPChunker = nltk.RegexpParser(pattern)
>>> sentence = 'criminal lawyer new york'.split()
>>> pos_tag(sentence)
[('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')]
>>> result = NPChunker.parse(pos_tag(sentence))
>>> result
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', 
[('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
>>> result = NPChunker.parse(pos_tag(sentence))
>>> result
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', [('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])
```

you are seeing a *string representation of the data structure in memory*.

When you type `result` at the interpreter prompt, what you get is the same as what you get if you type `repr(result)` at the interpreter prompt. It appears that you have saved this string representation in a file. That is unfortunate because this representation is not acceptable to `Tree.fromstring()`.

To save an acceptable version to a file you need to write out the `str()` (not the `repr()`) of the tree. You can see the difference here:

```
>>> result
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', [('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])
>>> str(result)
'(S (NP criminal/JJ lawyer/NN) (NP new/JJ york/NN))'
```

`Tree.fromstring()` is expecting the second of these formats.

To verify that this will do what you want:

```
>>> result2 = nltk.Tree.fromstring(str(result))
>>> result2
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', ['criminal/JJ', 'lawyer/NN']), Tree('NP', ['new/JJ', 'york/NN'])])
```

But that is for the future. You need to repair the file you have. Do the following:

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> input_string = "Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', [('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])"
```

I'm doing an inline assignment here, but of course you will be reading `input_string` from a text file.

```
>>> parsed_tree = eval(input_string)
>>> type(parsed_tree)
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'>
>>> str(parsed_tree)
'(S (NP criminal/JJ lawyer/NN) (NP new/JJ york/NN))'
```

This solution is suitable for use as a one-time emergency repair for your file. *Don't*  do it as a regular procedure.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules